# What is the mechanism used by std::thread to block and wait for the OS/hardware thread to finish?

Tags: c++, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I do not mean calling join(). I am interested in mechanics of what happens in join(). I assume there must be a system call to OS that will not return until the hardware thread completes. And how OS routine is signaled that a particular thread has completed. Just conceptual understanding.

Comment: On MS-Window probably `WaitForSingleObjectEx` on the native thread handle (the native thread handle becomes signalled when the thread exits) see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobjectex?redirectedfrom=MSDN  Note: there are a lot of wait function so it could be a related one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The OS's task scheduler maintains a status for every thread that exists.  This status indicates if the thread is running, ready to run, waiting for something, etc.  Whenever a CPU core becomes free, the scheduler looks through its list to find the next ready thread.

When a thread calls `std::thread::join`, it will end up dispatching a syscall to the OS kernel that says "I'm waiting on thread X".  When the kernel receives that syscall, it will move the thread into a waiting status and avoid scheduling it to run until thread X has terminated.  When thread X exits, the OS will mark the waiting thread ready to run so that it's in consideration to run the next time a CPU frees up.

The exact mechanism depends on the OS in question, but the concepts will be similar for pretty much any OS.  As an example, on Linux `std::thread::join` ends up calling `pthread_join`, which ends up doing a [`FUTEX_WAIT`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/futex.2.html) syscall to wait for the thread in question.  On Windows, it will make a call to [`WaitForSingleObjectEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/windows/win32/api/synchapi/nf-synchapi-waitforsingleobjectex).

Comment: Thank you! It is clear to me now. I guess similar mechanism is behind the conditional variable.

Comment: Generally yes, anything that requires the thread wait for something will work similarly.  Condition variables, I/O, etc.